# Writing performant C++ setters

Tags: c++, c++11

After reading Effective Modern C++ I'm trying to figure out best way how to pass arguments for setters in C++ classes; imagine following scenario:

You are writing application that parses input file (e.g. in CVS format), feeds it into model class and then passes list of instances to database driver for bulk insert.

We can talk about just the latest-and-greatest C++14; I wrote my attempt to represent this with one column:

```
class Person {
    std::wstring _name;
public:
    template<typename T>
    inline void setName(T&& name) { _name = std::forward<T>(name); }
};
```

I also wrote following snippet to test the performance:

```
const auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Person>> vec;
for (auto i = 0; i < 999999; i++)
{
    auto p = std::make_shared<Person>();
    p->setName(L"John Chester Doe");

    vec.emplace_back(p);
}   

const auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
std::cout << "Took " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - start).count() << " ms" << std::endl;
```

On my system this takes ~175ms compiled with MSVC2017 Release x64 with /O2, turned off SDL, no security checks (/sdl- /GS-). Out of curiosity I tried the same thing in C#:

```
class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
} 


var sw = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
var i = 0;
var vec = new System.Collections.Generic.List<Person>();
for (; i < 999999; i++)
{
    var p = new Person();
    p.Name = "John Chester Doe";
    vec.Add(p);
}
sw.Stop();
System.Console.WriteLine("Took {0}ms", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

And this yields 77ms in Release mode! So naturally my question is what I'm doing wrong? Why my C++ code is slower than C# code on what's essentially same operation?

I tried using struct in C++ (no difference), passing value by const ref (slower), passing value with std::move (slower). I also tried using noexcept (no big difference) even std::string (no big difference).

Thanks!

**Edit**

Thanks to everybody for suggestions, really appreciate it. It looks like best way for what I want to achieve would be something like this:

```
std::vector<Person> vec;
vec.reserve(999999);
for (auto i = 0; i < 999999; i++)
{
    vec.emplace_back();
    vec.back().setName(L"John Chester Doe");
}
```

This is 75ms with pre-allocation, without vec.reserve it's 130ms.

Comment: Did you try ```vec.reserve(999999);``` before the loop?

Comment: You're comparing contiguous memory (`std::vector`) to what sounds like a linked list type (`System.Collections.Generic.List`).  When calling `emplace_back` the vector might have to reallocate.  Better compare with `std::list` or use `vec.reserve(999999)` before the loop.  Also, comparing walltimes is an absolutely meaningless benchmark.

Comment: Now, get rid of `make_shared`, and actually use C++ like C++, instead of like C#. Only a small part of what the shown code does is actually related to invoking the setter. 90% of the work involved consists of nothing more than pushing a bunch of bits between various memory locations that have absolutely nothing to do, whatsoever, with the class member being set. Oh, and the vector vs list is also an issue. Comparing apples to oranges is not very useful, either.

Comment: @HenriMenke using std::list seems to be even slower, it is reporting 193ms.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Removing make_shared makes it even slower (218ms).

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk good suggestion, that cut it down to 158ms. Still, that's more then twice the time.

Comment: (1) `vec` incurs a hidden quadratic behavior when the vector needs to grow. Try reserving as suggested, or use `deque` if you think reserving is cheating. (2) Also, you don't need the `shared_ptr`'s. As commented, this adds some overhead for reference count management that is unnecessary for this collection. (3) I am not sure what you are trying to gain from the call to `std::forward`, but the idiomatic implementation would initialize `name` in the constructor.

Comment: Not much of a diffrence, but instead of ```system_clock``` use ```high_resolution_clock```.

Comment: What happens if you use ```push_back``` with a move instead of ```emplace_back```?

Comment: @jxh I'm interested in any way how to make this faster. I even tried preallocating array with pointers but I got 136ms. I'm starting to suspect that issue is with std::wstring instead.

Comment: However, given the structure of your code, after getting rid of shared, the inner loop should be: `vec.emplace_back(); vec.back().setName(...);`

Comment: @jxh all right! This seems to be winner with 74ms:
        std::vector<Person> vec;
 vec.reserve(999999);
 
 for (auto i = 0; i < 999999; i++)
 {
  vec.emplace_back();
  vec.back().setName(L"John Chester Doe");
 }

Comment: @shrpq As I said, walltimes are meaningless.  This is how you benchmark: http://quick-bench.com/sLh6rzdYjrVzo67PIT7PWMp7I_8

Comment: @HenriMenke Thanks, I didn't knew about that tool. However fastest option is not really what I look for since it requires same value and I want to use different values but better is what I'm looking for. Is there any way to make std::string faster by using other container?

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk odds are really good that `high_resolution_clock` is just an alias for `system_clock`

Comment: @shrpq out of general interest, what happens if you `std::vector<Person> vec(999999); for (auto & p: vec) { p.setName(L"John Chester Doe"); }`

Comment: @shrpq It really depends what requirements you have for the container.  If you only need to insert at the back as fast as possible, use [`std::stack`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack) or [`std::deque`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque). 
 I recommend watching this talk about the performance of standard containers: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LrVi9LHP8Bk

Comment: @user4581301 If I will update it to std::vector<Person> vec(999999, Person()); and then use your part it's 86 ms so slightly worse then emplace.

Comment: `Person p; p.setName(...); std::vector<Person> vec(999999, p);`

Comment: @user4581301 In VS it uses the High performance counters of Windows.

Comment: @shrpq it would seem that you are now capable of posting an answer to your question.

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk Ah. They aliased `steady_clock`, did they?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding is that what C# compiler does in the background roughly transforms to following C++ code:

```
class Person {
    std::wstring _name;
public:
    template<typename T>
    inline void setName(T&& name) { _name = std::forward<T>(name); }
};
```

And for the insertion part:

```
std::vector<Person> vec;
vec.reserve(999999);
for (auto i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
{
    vec.emplace_back();
    vec.back().setName(L"John Chester Doe");
}
```

Thanks again for your time, if there are any other suggestions how to improve this I'll be happy to hear it.

Comment: For C++, it would seem to make more sense to pass the name to the constructor, so you don't end up initializing it twice. Also (not being C# literate) are strings wide characters in C#? Copying 2x the bytes could also have a performance impact

Comment: @jwm they able to store utf-16 strings but how that's implemented storage-wise is unknown, `Char` in .NET is utf-16 character

Answer (score 0):

"Comparing oranges to apples" is best description I can give here . Your C# code  got closest C++ equivalent like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <deque>
#include <chrono>
#include <string>

struct Person {
    std::wstring _name;

    Person() = default;
    Person(Person&& p) = default;
    Person(const Person& p) = default;
    Person(const std::wstring& n) : _name(n) {}
};

int main()
{
    std::deque<Person> vec; 
    const std::wstring n =  L"John Chester Doe";
    const auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    for (auto i = 0; i < 999999; i++)
    {
        vec.emplace_back(n);
    }   

    const auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::cout << "Took " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - start).count() << " ms" << std::endl;
}
```

Which is at least 3 times faster than your variant. Perhaps I could make it faster, moving allocation of all memory into initialization of deque, but that will change the loop to a ranged one. Yes, C# does same things as java does. It tries to offload most of predictable work to compilation time, e.g. collecting similar literals, projecting usable memory and allocating it more effectively, etc. Mostly because CLR works on principles similar to java machine.

Comment: Sorry, but while it's faster then my variant it still is not faster then C#. In my test this results into 130ms. Even with perfect-forwarding template for constructor it's not faster.

Comment: @shrpq Your wariant gave me 590-600 ms, mine yielded 110 ms, so proportions do not match, which is strange.  to test it properly you should make test unpredictable. C# simply would create and fill list with 99999 copies of same object in _compile_ time. You can code this, by initializing container that way in C++. That's likely reason why it's faster. That's one of advantages of such languages because they designed that compiler can do this. Their limitations are in different area..in performing at executing elementary operations and in requirement to memory and infrastructure.

Comment: Sorry, but that's not what it generates, here is ILDAsm output. Hmm, cannot paste it here but you can see it calls the Add function on List and creates new objects. If that statement would be true then the time for execution will be linear regardless of number of elements which is not true.

Comment: That's true but you can pretty much force the same thing using NGEN - if I do that then the time goes down by ~10% so there are some extra things happening in JIT. Still, I don't think that C# compiler (at any level) can detect this kind of scenario because otherwise it will just dump whole structure into memory as one big blob which will be linear time. Better yet since I'm not really using that structure there is not even need to keep it around so the whole thing should just close immediately.